как исправить ошибку с Scopes used for OpenID Connect
начал работу с DropBox API создал приложение и как только захожу в Permissions чтоб настроить приложение вижу эту ошибку:
Scopes used for OpenID Connect.
At this time, team-scoped apps cannot request OpenID Connect scopes.
OpenID scopes must be explicity set in the "scope" parameter on /oauth2/authorize to be requested.
прочитал перевел и понял что необходим доступ.
Пока не вкуриваю как что работает, подскажите пожалуйста как исправить и возможно ли это?
а так я пытаюсь скопировать токен доступа пока не знаю где найти чтоб мое приложение имело доступ DropBox
